# Action Button for Notification does not appear in Samsung S7 Device android

Tags: java, android, service, notifications

I have Developed a Background Service to show Notifications for my android app. These notifications contain Action Buttons to record the response of the user.
But my main problem is that these action buttons doesn't appear on Samsung S7 device. Any help would be appreciated. I can share my source code or i can add code snippets here if the problem is not related to build.gradle etc.
I really don't know the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen so many problem with Samsung when loading different view elements, Try to add button programmatically when it disappears on XML. Use handlers.

Comment: notifications work fine on every device except s7. I have put action buttons for notifications through Intent and Pending Intent in a service.

Answer (score 0):

check if notification in device is enabled for your app.

Comment: Notifications appear on the device. There is no problem with the notification. But Action Buttons for notification doesn't appear.